# How can I make Liferay login portlet redirect to maximized version to display validation errors?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-velocity

I've got a theme which has a login portlet embedded in the header and I dont wish for validation messages to appear on this login portlet, instead I want Liferay to redirect to the maximized version of the login portlet with the validation errors.

Is there any easy way to do this through the Velocity template files?

The best workaround I can come up with is to hardcode a HTML form which posts to the login struts action which seems to show validation errors on a maximized loging portlet

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe Liferay 6.0 has the capability to overwrite portlet code using a VM. It is, however, a new feature in the upcoming 6.1 release.

But if you're tied into Liferay 6.0, you may create a hook plugin to tackle this problem.

- Create a hook plugin.
- In your hook.xml define:

```xml
    <hook>
        <custom-jsp-dir>/META-INF/custom_jsps</custom-jsp-dir>
    </hook>
```

- In copy the original `login.jsp` from Liferay Portal to `/META-INF/custom_jsps/html/portlet/login.jsp`.
- You'll want to modify the form action's URL to have window state maximized. You can do so by adding the windowState attribute to the tag lib that generates the URL. For Example:

```xml
    <portlet:actionURL windowState="<%= LiferayWindowState.MAXIMIZED.toString() %>" />
```

After deploying this hook plugin, the logins should go to a maximized state unless redirected by a successful login.